# String comparison in VBScript

Tags: windows, vbscript, string-comparison, nagios

I wrote a check for [Nagios](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nscplus) to detect if the currently installed Version of **Java** is the newest or if there are Updates to be applied.

First I get both the currently installed version of Java (using some code I found to retrieve the currently installed version) and the newest available version (using the document http://java.com/applet/JreCurrentVersion2.txt).
Then I transform them using regular expressions (result: *$1.$2.$3*) to the same style, e.g.:

> 7.0.25

When printing the transformed versions via **Wscript.Echo** I can see, both are identical, but the String Comparison Operator **StrComp()** returns always **false**, if the Strings are equal or different.
With an old version installed I get

> Critical: Java Version 7.0.24 - available: 7.0.25

which is intended, but with the correct version I also get

> Critical: Java Version 7.0.25 - available: 7.0.25

instead of

> OK: Java Version 7.0.25

I attached the complete script down below:

**check_java.vbs**

```
On Error Resume Next

CONST rOK = 0
CONST rWarning = 1
CONST rCritical = 2
CONST rUnknown = 3

blnJavaInstalled = False
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")
Set colProducts = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT Version FROM Win32_Product")
For Each objProduct in colProducts
  If Err.Number = 0 Then
    If (InStr(UCase(objProduct.Name),"JAVA") And Not InStr(UCase(objProduct.Name),"UPDATER")) Then
      blnJavaInstalled = True
      version = objProduct.Version
    End If
  End If
Next
If blnJavaInstalled <> True Then
  Wscript.Echo "No Java found."
  Wscript.Quit(rUnknown)
End If

Set objRegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
objRegEx.Global = True
objRegEx.IgnoreCase = True
objRegEx.Pattern = "([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+).([0-9]*[1-9])0*"

curVersion = objRegEx.Replace(version, "$1.$2.$3")

Dim o
Set o = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
o.open "GET", "http://java.com/applet/JreCurrentVersion2.txt", False
o.send

Set objRegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
objRegEx.Global = True
objRegEx.IgnoreCase = True
objRegEx.Pattern = "1\.([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)_([0-9]+)"

newVersion = objRegEx.Replace(o.responseText, "$1.$2.$3")

If StrComp(curVersion, newVersion) Then
    Wscript.Echo "OK: Java Version " & curVersion
    Wscript.Quit(rOK)
Else
    Wscript.Echo "Critical: Java Version " & curVersion & " - available: " & newVersion
    Wscript.Quit(rCritical)
End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`o.responseText` has a trailing newline, so you're actually comparing `7.0.25` to `7.0.25\r\n`, which obviously are not equal. You can reveal the trailing newline with something like this:

```
>>> WScript.Echo "_" & o.responseText & "_"
_7.0.25
_
```

Either change your second regular expression to

```
objRegEx.Pattern = "1\.([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)_([0-9]+)[\s\S]*"
```

or remove the newline from `o.responseText` before doing the regexp replacement:

```
newVersion = objRegEx.Replace(Replace(o.responseText, vbNewLine, ""), "$1.$2.$3")
```

Comment: Thanks, this was the part I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

[StrComp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ya4w6fwy%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) returns 0 (False) if the strings compared are equal. So switch the branches of your If statement. As you are not interested in which of the strings is greater or smaller, consider using the = operator (less risk of mistake).

Comment: I experimented with this as well, but since the Strings were always different (see marked answers), I couldn't resolve the issue with inserting " = 0" to StrComp, so I reverted the changes I did. With the solution in the other answer and your information, I got it working. Thanks